# ¿How to set maximum downloads or sockets or whatever, in Apache and or PHP?

Tags: apache-2.2, php

I made a PHP script, running from my localhost, that streams files from a remote server and serves them. I do this so I can rename the files prior to the browser shows the dialog to save them, through header( "filename:..." )

Anyway, although the remote server allows many simultaneous file downloads at good rates, when they stream through my local apache/php I can't get more than 6 at the same time.

When I try to download the 7th, the save as dialog appears as soon as the sixth download has finished.

I'm almost sure this is some limit imposed by php.ini or apache's httpd.ini, but don't have a clue about which one is it. do you?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure it's not your local machine limiting your downloads rather than the remote server? These settings can be changed in apache (and also PHP I think), but the default setting isn't 6 (as far as I know)

Comment: actually you're right

Answer (score 0):

It's my browser limiting the connections... It has nothing to do with Apache or PHP... onetipaday.com/2007/07/31/

Comment: Please post comments as comments, not answers. This is a question and answer site, not a discussion forum.

Comment: It's not a comment, it's the answer, I found it so I post it here.

Comment: Glad you resolved this issue. Please be sure to mark your answer as "accepted" when you are able.